# SharePoint Configuration wizard failed - cannot create new web app

Tags: sharepoint

The problem is that I cannot create new web app on SharePoint 2016, it takes a too long time, loading infinitely with hours until I end it, and the central admin gives `404 not found`

First I restarted and made sure the SQL server is started and the farm admin account has correct roles all passes, but with no luck. Finally, I decided to start the configuration wizard but I found this error

```
WEBCONFIG.ACCSRV.XML, does not have element "configuration/configSections/sectionGroup[@name='SharePoint']" or it is invalid.
```

I have compared this file with its pair on one server, which it works found they are the same content. Any help, please.

Comment: Delete all unnecessary web application from Central admin, run psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force in SharePoint management shell, would you get any errors?

Comment: thank you comment inspire me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is as follows:
1-Delete All unused Web Apps
2-Delete Some unused IIS sites which are used the ports of SharePoint (port 80,...)
3-clear SharePoint recycle bin
4-confirm all SharePoint service and IIs App pools are running " as I found Service Application App Pool was stopped"
5-Delete the additional trust provider

The main reason is the user was trying to install SharePoint add-in so he changes the trust and changes the port of default site of SharePoint and central admin seeking to change them to HTTPS and then try to create many web apps which have been created with the corrupted web. configs and those changes make all this hassle

I hope this Question may help others